# Can a massless virtual graviton decay into a Higgs Boson and two γ-photons in the LHC at CERN?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-gravity, higgs, large-hadron-collider

Τheoretically, is it possible?
G--> H--> γγ

And if not, why?

Comment: Since there is no standard implementation of quantum gravity, i guess there is no way to answer this question?

Comment: @AlmostClueless This question can be answered through perturbative quantum gravity, which many believe is likely a valid low-energy limit of any ultimate theory of quantum gravity. The conclusion should be that this process has an astronomically small, and unmeasurable, effect on the probability of producing a higgs in LHC collisions

Comment: Note on phrasing - nothing massless can decay. Especially into something massive. But your question also has a contradiction "can a virtual graviton decay" is not the correct way to phrase it. Decay is something that happens to on-shell (real/not virtual) particles. The most sensible version of this question is more like "can a Higgs be produced through a virtual graviton in LHC collisions."

Comment: @AXensen "The most sensible version of this question is more like "can a Higgs be produced through a virtual graviton  in LHC collisions." I agree, not really a decay but more like a phase transition mechanism of a graviton to a Higgs Boson during the LHC collisions. What is ecxactly causing this hypothsized phase transition of the graviton into a Higgs scalar boson? Well, the Higgs spin 0 boson could actually be the static imprint of a spin-2 superluminal  vibrating graviton string that was brought out due to the collision of its superliminal oscillation and then decayed tο two γ photons.

Comment: @Markoul11 This has nothing to do with phase transitions. I recommend you learn about Feynman diagrams. It's very normal for particles to be produced through other virtual particles. The rest of your comment has gone deep into the realm of crackpot and I won't be responding further... "the Higgs spin 0 boson could actually be the static imprint of a spin-2 superluminal vibrating graviton string" is not physics. It's words that sound like the things that physicists say. But there's no underlying meaning to them - they don't imply any specific quantitative predictions about the universe.

Comment: "nothing massless can decay. Especially into something massive." that is not true. See Breit-Wheeler process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit%E2%80%93Wheeler_process

Comment: @AXensen I don't agree about this being a "crackpot" hypothesis. $G\to H$ of one particle transforming to another single particle is possible especially if the vacuum is a kind of Boson condensate and we are now talking about the scalar thus only static particle in the SM the Higgs Boson, which implies that it could be actually a static collision imprint (snapshot) of a non-zero spin other hypothetical elementary particle like the spin-2 massless graviton. Scalar particles are by definition massive. One to one transform $G\to H$ is possible assuming a process similar to neutrino oscillation.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the title:

> Can a massless virtual graviton decay into a Higgs Boson and two γ-photons in the LHC at CERN?

Massless particles of whatever type cannot decay  within the mainstream physics because of the mathematical nature of Lorentz transformations that involves conservation of energy. In addition, there is no center of mass for a massless particle, that always has the velocity c.

Within mainstream physics mathematics any massive particle can decay as long as energy momentum  and angular momentum conservation are obeyed, and also important, the main stream physic quantum numbers of the particles are taken into account correctly.

In your hypothesis of :

G--> H--> γγ

where G is a massive graviton, it is only the decay of  G--> H that is a question, whose answer is, if the mass of the supposed graviton is larger than the mass of the Higgs boson, there will be a probability for the graviton to decay to a Higgs, dependent on the theory that the graviton is supposed to follow. The Higgs will go on to decay into whatever it does as seen in the [PDG page](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/listings/rpp2013-list-higgs-boson.pdf) .

If you meant , G--> H + γγ , it is another question, which again will depend on the mass of the G being large enough at the center of mass.  Whether one should search for the existence of a new particle which decays into H + γγ in order to detect the existence of a graviton is a question that within mainstream physics has no meaning , considering [how weak the gravitational interaction](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/couple.html) is with respect to all other possible ones that could give rise to such a particle.

Comment: Thank you (ευχαριστώ) for your detailed answer, We know already that a spin-0 Higgs Boson can decay to $H\to γγ$ . What I am really asking if $G\to H$ is theoretically possible, possibly due to a phase transition mechanism and not really a decay? But no I am not interested for the massive graviton but for the more general accepted model of the hypothetical massless graviton spin-2 Boson. You are right using c limit this is not possible. But what if hypothetically the massless graviton is initially in an superluminal harmonic oscillation energy state (larger than Planck frequency)?...continue

Comment: ,,,continue. And the partial ~126GeV LHC proton beams collision kinetic energy decelerated the angular frequency of the spin-2 graviton  just enough to phase transition it to luminal c speed thus an unstable  static scalar spin-0 imprint (i.e. Higgs Boson) of the stable massless superluminal spin-2  graviton? Of course after that the unstable massive spin-0 Higgs Boson that carries the ~126 GeV partial collision energy (equal to the initial lost oscillation energy of the graviton) can decay to two opposite flying spin-1 γ-photons inside ATLAS detector. https://tinyurl.com/5we9ekrp

Comment: This model you  propose is not within the standard model and the order of magnitude of possible interactions that are allowed, The standard mainstream model fits existing data and is successful in predictions, and as I said, anything having to do with gravity will have a very very small probability and so cannot be checked with the LHC data.

Comment: I agree that it is highly hypothetical what I suggest but still IMHO I believe it is possible. One to one transform $G\to H$ is possible assuming a process similar to neutrino oscillation exists in this case.

Comment: This is getting confusing. This article here, 
atlas.physicsmasterclasses.org/en/zpath_graviton.htm says that graviton can definitely decay into 2 spin-1 photons, Although it does not refer to any mass for the graviton? The wiki article here, https://tinyurl.com/75xws6d8 , confirms (see zero spin requirement table row) that the graviton can decay into a di-photons γγ pair spin-1. The question now is, (see related Atlas paper https://tinyurl.com/8wncwjf5) how they differentiated that the di-photons observed was not due to they decay of spin-2 graviton but rather a spin-0 Higgs Boson?

Comment: Your first link is not working. ( atlas.physicsmasterclasses.org/en/zpath_graviton.htm) . the second link accepts mainstream physics impossibility of the graviton having a measurable  probability due to very small coupling, so does not consider it.